# how can i read a nested nodes xml file in c# and fill the same xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, list, file

i have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Groups>
  <Group>
    <GroupId>1</GroupId>
    <GroupName>11</GroupName>
    <GroupExplanation>111</GroupExplanation>
    <ImageSource>1111</ImageSource>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <GroupId>2</GroupId>
    <GroupName>22</GroupName>
    <GroupExplanation>222</GroupExplanation>
    <ImageSource>2222</ImageSource>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <GroupId>3</GroupId>
    <GroupName>33</GroupName>
    <GroupExplanation>333</GroupExplanation>
    <ImageSource>3333</ImageSource>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

and the class that defines it:

```
namespace RepositoryAndAccountingWebMVC.Models
{
    [XmlRoot("Groups"), XmlType("Groups")]
    public class Group
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GroupId")]
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GroupName")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GroupExplanation")]
        public string GroupExplanation { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ImageSources")]
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

i have a list (ListGroups = new List()).
how can i fill the list with xml file data?
and how to save the new group records into the same file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the root element in you model:

```
[XmlRoot("Groups"), XmlType("Groups")]
public class GroupRoot
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Group")]
    public List<Group> Group { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could load your xml using :

```
        string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Groups><Group><GroupId>1</GroupId><GroupName>11</GroupName><GroupExplanation>111</GroupExplanation><ImageSource>1111</ImageSource></Group><Group><GroupId>2</GroupId><GroupName>22</GroupName><GroupExplanation>222</GroupExplanation><ImageSource>2222</ImageSource></Group><Group><GroupId>3</GroupId><GroupName>33</GroupName><GroupExplanation>333</GroupExplanation><ImageSource>3333</ImageSource></Group></Groups>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GroupRoot));

        TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

        // Unserialize the root element and all children
        var root = (GroupRoot)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        foreach (Group group in root.Group) {
              // action on each group
        }
```

And to save changes from the model to Xml :

```
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, root);
        writer.Close();
```